# solve 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider
$$
x^2 y''+y'=x-1,
$$
where $y=y(x)$ and $x>0$. I've tried the power method but obtained a divergent series. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

The equation can be rewritten as
$$
y''+\frac{1}{x^2}y'=\frac{x-1}{x^2},
$$
and then first solved for $z=y'$ using the integrating factor approach. The solution is
$$
z=y'=e^{1/x}\int^x e^{-1/t}\frac{t-1}{t^2} dt,
$$
whence
$$
y=\int^x\left[e^{1/s}\int^s e^{-1/t}\frac{t-1}{t^2} dt\right]ds.
$$

Is there a way to express this solution in terms of elementary functions with no integration involved? I just fail to see one.

I would actually be interested in finding an expansion of the solution into a series of powers of $x$. How would I go about obtaining such an expansion?

Comment: Have you tried integrating factor?

Comment: Yes, of course, that did give the solution in a closed form (as a double integral that cannot be evaluated), but I'd like to have the solution as a series.

Comment: i think a solution in the known elementary function is not possible

Comment: It's a first order with $z=y'$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I agree. I would be happy to have the solution in the form of a series of powers of $x$, but am not sure how to construct such a series.

Comment: I believe the solution cannot be given in elementary functions, you will need at least the Exponential integral function.

Comment: In general (as in this case), for a linear differential equation at an irregular singular point, series solutions have radius of convergence zero.